# NGINX, uWSGI, Flask: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, raspbian

I am developing my application stack using NGINX as web server and uWSGI as application server on a Raspbian Pixel. When I invoke the server in the browser I get an 'Internal Server Error'.
My lab_app_nginx.conf looks like this.

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name localhost;
charset     utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;

location /static {
    root /var/www/lab_app/;
}

location / { try_files $uri @labapp; }
location @labapp {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.sock;
}}
```

My lab_app_uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/lab_app

#python module to import
app =/var/www/lab_app/hello1.py
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/lab_app/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666                  
callable = app
```

My hello1.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
   return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Here is what the log file says

```
[pid: 1103|app: -1|req: -1/1] 192.168.10.12 () {38 vars in 650 bytes} [Tue Jun 20 23:38:40 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

What could be the problem

Comment: Do not use port 80, it is for system things. Try another one, linke 8080 (default for flask)

Comment: @AdiletMaratov Still not working